# How to use xpath or css locator to find text in non-identifiable html tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap each of the

elements separately but they don't have any unique class or id identifier. See a sample of the html structure below:

```
<div class="post-wrap">
    <h1 class="entry-title">Elizabeth</h1>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p><strong>Movie:</strong> Some text</p>
        <p><strong>Hook:</strong> Some text</p>
        <p><strong>Inciting Event:</strong> Some text</p>
        <p><strong>First Plot Point:</strong> Some text</p>
        <p><strong>First Pinch Point:</strong> Some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the easiest css or xpath locator to get the text out of each of the paragraphs? I have to go through a couple of hundred of these pages and they don't always have the same section structure so using the

. This method doesn't work.

Tried these options but nothing returned.

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'entry-content')]//p[contains(@strong, 'Hook')]").getall()
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'entry-content')]//p[contains(text(),'Inciting Event')]").getall()
```

Comment: can you share the url?, Also which portions of the text are you trying to scrape?  What is inside the `strong` tags?  or what is on the outside?  or both?

Comment: Sure, here's the page in the example. https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/movie-storystructure/elizabeth/
I'm trying to scrap the site and exporting the data by sorting the data in the strong> heading into a csv file. There's about 500 of these pages so the //p//text() won't help me sort the text.

Comment: So are you saying that the text inside the `<strong>` elements is the header and the rest of the text is the column value?

Comment: Yes that would the most ideal case!

Comment: That is what I do in my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath will extract all text as an entity.

```
//p//text()
```

Comment: Do you really think this is helpful?  The chances that there are only those specific `p` tags on the whole page seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract all of the text inside of the `<strong>` tags to use as keys and the rest of the paragraph text to use as the value, then what you could do is simply iterate through all of the p tags that are children of the `div` with 'entry-content' as the class.  Then extract the text from just the `strong` tag for the label, and then extract everything that isn't in the `strong` tag to be the value, then yield the whole thing as one item once the loop has finished.

For example:

```
def parse_story(self, response):
    item = {"title" : response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()}
    for paragraph in response.xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/p"):
        label = paragraph.xpath("./strong/text()").get()
        text = paragraph.xpath("./text()").get()
        if label:
            item[label] = text if text else ''
    yield item
```

Which would yield:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Elizabeth",
    "Movie:": " Directed by Shekhar Kapur",
    "Hook:": " Elizabeth is happy enough, even though imprisoned. She dances with her ladies and makes love with Lord Robert, her childhood sweetheart. Her world is presented as one of a comfortable home, where she is surrounded by people who adore and serve her.",
    "Inciting Event:": " After a Protestant conspiracy against the Catholic Queen Mary, Elizabeth is falsely implicated and taken to the Tower. She meets the dying Queen, realizes she will soon be Queen herself, but refuses to promise to uphold the Catholic faith. Rather, she insists she will what is right for \u201cmy people\u201d according to her own conscious.",
    "First Plot Point:": " Elizabeth is taken to the palace and crowned Queen. Almost immediately, it is put to her that her most important duty is marrying\u2014either Spain or France. She resists, in no small part because she is in love with Lord Robert. It is made clear that her opinions as a leader are not thought of in high regard.",
    "First Pinch Point:": " When her advisers almost unanimously clamor for her to send troops to eliminate the French bastion in Scotland, she reluctantly agrees\u2014but immediately regrets going against her own better judgment when she receives word of the massacre. She feels she has sent her people\u2014her \u201cchildren\u201d as represented by the wounded boy who brings back word\u2014to the slaughter. She weeps before a portrait of her father, Henry VIII, feeling she will never measure up to him as a leader.",
    "Midpoint:": " Elizabeth leads the charge against the bishops, convincing them to sign an accord so that both Protestants and Catholics may live together peaceably. She does so with her own womanly charm, putting the combative bishops at their ease, but also the firmness of her own convictions. She does not hide behind her council this time (although Walsingham helps by locking up the most contentious bishops). She also agrees to meet her French suitor, the Duke of Anjou.",
    "Second Pinch Point:": " After learning Lord Robert is already married and discovering the Duke of Anjou in the midst of an orgy, Elizabeth refuses to see any more suitors. She demands Lord Robert, in particular, \u201cgrow up\u201d and take responsibility for his own foolishness and his role as her subject\u2014rather than her lover.",
    "Third Plot Point:": " Walsingham kills the French Marie Guise, ridding Elizabeth of one of her prime enemies. When Lord Robert suggests a marriage treaty with Spain, she dismisses him.",
    "Climax:": " Elizabeth realizes her councilors\u2019 policies will eventually subjugate England through a marriage treaty. Even though she is \u201conly a woman,\u201d she determines to follow her heart and to protect England by remaining a Virgin. She dismisses her main councilor.",
    "Climactic Moment:": " Elizabeth authorizes that the Catholics who have plotted against her\u2014particularly the Duke of Norfolk who covets her throne\u2014should be executed.",
    "Resolution:": " She takes her place as an icon for the people\u2014the Virgin Queen."
  }
]
```